# Question About Integration And Its Rules

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I couldn't solve this problem because I don't even know how to start with it. Can someone guide me?

$$\left.{ \text{If a continuous function g satisfies; }  }   { \int_{0}^{4} {g {(\frac{x}{2})}} dx = A }\\ { \int_{0}^{4} {g {(2 x)}} dx = B }\\ { \text{Find }  } \\ { \int_{1}^{2} {x g {(2 x ^ {2})}} dx } \right.$$

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Please see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Have you tried using integration by parts?

Answer (score 1):

By a change of variable what you want to find ($2x^2=t$) is $\frac{1}{4} \int_2^8 g(t) dt$.
Again, by a change of variable you can get $B=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^8 g(t) dt$ by posing $2x=t$ and $A=2 \int_0^2 g(t)dt$ where again $x=2t$. So the result of your integral will be:
$$\frac{1}{4}(2B-\frac{A}{2})$$
because $\int_2^8g(t)dt=\int_0^8g(t)dt - \int_0^2 g(t)dt$.